# Replacing charachers in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, utf-8, phpbb3

I have transfered a big phpbb3 database from a latin1 database to an utf-8
Everything went ok, now I need to change the "strange" characters in the database. Yesterday I found a method that worked, now I can't find it anymore, I tried:

```
update phpbb_topics set topic_title = replace(topic_title, 'Ã', 'à');
update phpbb_topics set topic_title = replace(topic_title, 'Ã¨', 'è');
```

Basically I need to change all the Ã characters in the table field to à and so on.

How can you do this?

Thanks

Comment: The fact that you have strange characters in your database suggests that the conversion did not go well. In fact, it went wrong.

Comment: From a quick Google search, your query seems correct. Are the fields not updating or is something else going wrong? Have you tried doing something fairly safe like changing all instances of "x" with "__x__"? Something you can see working but easily reverse?

Comment: @rikh yeah, it went very very wrong, but I can't do nothing about it this is what the hoster gave me :-(
@Anthony you'r right, I tried to another table and indeed it works, looks like something to do with the BLOB type of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update phpbb_topics set topic_title = replace(replace(topic_title, 'Ã¨', 'è'), 'Ã', 'à');

You should answer yourself following questions:

- what binary data is stored in database (use ascii() function or SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE)
- what binary data is sent to client (it is not always the same as stored)
- how your client shows received binary data? (try different clients and different options)

Answer (score 0):

I would dump it to a .sql file and then replace the chars with sed or a text editor( if the file is not to large). After that you run the script again. 
Maybe there is a way to do this in the database directly but I don't know it.

The problem about my solution is that its not atomic. Changes to the db between the dump and the reinsertion are lost.

Greetings
Raffael